# MyDoggy: Make content resize when window is resized instead of bottom ToolWindow?

Tags: java, swing, docking

MyDoggy documentation and examples aren't really helpful (the TutorialSet has the same issue and MyDoggySet has unreadable code), so maybe someone here can help me out.

I am building an editor and I would like dockable frames. I used MyDoggy but I have an issue: when I resize the window, instead of resizing the content, it resizes the bottom ToolWindow, like this:

[image: Before resizing]

into this:

[image: After resizing]

How can I make the text editor (the tabbed component) get resized instead of the ToolWindow?

Here is some relevant code (sorry for the mess, it's from the countless attempts to tackle this problem):

```
toolWindowManager = new MyDoggyToolWindowManager();
contentManager = toolWindowManager.getContentManager();
MultiSplitContentManagerUI contentManagerUI = new MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI();
contentManager.setContentManagerUI(contentManagerUI);
contentManagerUI.setShowAlwaysTab(true);
contentManagerUI.setTabPlacement(TabPlacement.TOP);
errorDisplay = toolWindowManager.registerToolWindow("Errors",
        "Errors", null, new ErrorList(), ToolWindowAnchor.BOTTOM);
        errorDisplay.setType(ToolWindowType.DOCKED);
DockedTypeDescriptor dockedTypeDescriptor = (DockedTypeDescriptor) errorDisplay
        .getTypeDescriptor(ToolWindowType.DOCKED);
dockedTypeDescriptor.setDockLength(100);
dockedTypeDescriptor.setPopupMenuEnabled(true);
RepresentativeAnchorDescriptor<?> representativeAnchorDescriptor = errorDisplay
        .getRepresentativeAnchorDescriptor();
representativeAnchorDescriptor.setPreviewEnabled(true);
representativeAnchorDescriptor.setPreviewDelay(1500);
representativeAnchorDescriptor.setPreviewTransparentRatio(0.4f);
errorDisplay.setAvailable(true);
errorDisplay.setActive(true);
newDocument();
for (ToolWindow window : toolWindowManager.getToolWindows())
    window.setAvailable(true);
```

newDocument :

```
...
Content c = cm.addContent("editor_untitled" + id, "Untitled " + id,
            null, new EditorPane(), null, new MultiSplitConstraint(curDoc));
...
TabbedContentUI contentUI = (TabbedContentUI) c.getContentUI();
contentUI.setCloseable(true);
contentUI.setDetachable(true);
contentUI.setTransparentMode(true);
contentUI.setTransparentRatio(0.7f);
contentUI.setTransparentDelay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution hidden in the sourceforge forum thing, not indexed by Google for some reason.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mydoggy/forums/forum/614985/topic/3263489

All I had to do was set the pushaway mode to horizontal.

```
toolWindowManager.getToolWindowManagerDescriptor().setPushAwayMode(PushAwayMode.HORIZONTAL);
```